# Toast didnt work

Tags: android, toast

I have android project v.2.1. 
 and I have a code, in the code I have Toast, but it doesn't work. Why?

```
    public void click(){

    TextView color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    switch(i){

    case 1: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); color.setText("Красный");
        break;
    case 2: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb (255, 127, 0) );
    color.setText("Оранжевый");
        break;
    case 3: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    color.setText("Желтый");
        break;
    case 4: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN) ;
    color.setText("Зеленый");
        break;
    case 5: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb (0,191,255) );
    color.setText("Голубой");
        break;
    case 6: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE );
    color.setText("Синий");
        break;
    case 7: table.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb (160,32,240) );
    color.setText("Фиолетовый");
        break;
    case 8: //  i=1; 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы прошли все цвета",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< MY TOAST!
        break;
    }
```

Toast not in an OnCreate.

Comment: Your toast will only fire when i == 8, because of `case 8:`

Answer (score 1):

Your statement to create and show the Toast is correct. It is likely you are having a logic error are you absolutely positive that your switch statement is using case 8? It would be a good idea to put some log statements inside each case that print out which case it is so you can debug what is happening easier.

Im not certain what the rest of your activity looks like but this appears to be some kind of click listener callback method. If that is the case you should not have

```
TextView color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Inside a click callback. Doing so means that findViewById() is going to get called every time your view gets clicked. Since this is a relatively expensive method to call its more appropriate to call it once in your onCreate and just keep the reference that you get back for all other times you'll need it.